# How to handle the persistentContainer load failure case

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

This is code I'm using for creating the persistent container for Core Data stack.

I want to handle the failure case when persistentContainer is not nil and is already loaded in the CoredataHandler shared instance class.

CoredataHandler.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isStoreLoaded;
```

CoredataHandler.m file

```
@implementation CoredataHandler

+(CoredataHandler *) sharedInstance
{
    static CoredataHandler *shared = nil;
    
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        
        shared = [[self alloc] init];
        
    });
    
    return shared;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _persistentContainer = self.persistentContainer;
    }
    return self;
}


@synthesize persistentContainer = _persistentContainer;

- (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {
    // The persistent container for the application. This implementation creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the application to it.
    @synchronized (self) {
        NSURL * storeURL  =  [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDataBase"];

        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            NSPersistentContainer *container = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"MyDataBase"];

            NSPersistentStoreDescription * persistentStoreDescription = [[NSPersistentStoreDescription alloc] initWithURL:storeURL];
            persistentStoreDescription.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = YES;
            [persistentStoreDescription setOption:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey];
            persistentStoreDescription.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = YES;
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = @[persistentStoreDescription];

            [container loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                    /*
                     Typical reasons for an error here include:
                     * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                     * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                     * The device is out of space.
                     * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                     */
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    //abort();

                    self->_isStoreLoaded = NO;

                }
                self->_isStoreLoaded = YES;
                return;

            }];

            if (self.isStoreLoaded) {
                _persistentContainer = container;
            }
        }  else {
            if (![self persistentStoreExistsWithStoreURL:storeURL]) {
                _persistentContainer = nil;
            }
        }
    }
    return _persistentContainer;

}
```

I have tried by checking if the store exists in the path

```
-(BOOL)persistentStoreExistsWithStoreURL:(NSURL *)url {

    if (url &&
        url.isFileURL &&
        [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:url.path]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}


-(NSBatchUpdateResult *)executeRequestForNSBatchUpdateResult:(NSBatchUpdateRequest *)updateRequest {
    NSBatchUpdateResult *batchUpdateResult = nil;
    if (!self.persistentContainer) {
        return nil;
    }

    if (self.persistentContainer.viewContext) {
        batchUpdateResult = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[self.persistentContainer.viewContext executeRequest:updateRequest error:nil];
    }
    return batchUpdateResult;
}


@end
```

```
-(void)markItmesInCategory:(NSNumber*)categoryId {
    NSBatchUpdateRequest *req= [[NSBatchUpdateRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Items_table"];
    req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryId=%d",[channelKey intValue]];
    req.propertiesToUpdate = @{
        @"status" : @(1)
    };
    req.resultType = NSUpdatedObjectsCountResultType;
    CoredataHandler * dbHandler = [CoredataHandler sharedInstance];

    NSError * fetchError = nil;

    NSBatchUpdateResult *batchUpdateResult = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[dbHandler executeRequestForNSBatchUpdateResult:req];

    if (batchUpdateResult) {
        NSLog(@"updated rows", batchUpdateResult.result);
    }
}
```

How to handle the case if its already loaded object in the shared instance class and if the store as some permission issue in accessing

Example :
The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.

Comment: When and where in your code do you want to check that? `CoredataHandler` is only initialized once when it is accessed, so when can "failure case when persistentContainer is not nil and is already loaded in the CoredataHandler shared instance class" occur?

Comment: I wanted to check in CoredataHandler  when accessing persistentContainer method in else part  is the core datastore is accessible or not so that I can handle if the store is not accessible when the phone is locked in case of NSFileProtectionComplete